# Does the development time in Massive Dev Chart include the agitation time?

Tags: film, technique, developing, developer

I'm looking at the [Massive Dev Chart website](https://www.digitaltruth.com/devchart.php?Film=%25Ilford%20HP5%25&Developer=%25D-76%25&mdc=Search&TempUnits=C&TimeUnits=D). It shows a table like this:

[image]

Does the time shown there include the agitation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agitation time is included in the development time.

Assuming you are using a small tank (this type seems to be the most common) the agitation is by inversion.

[image: paterson tank]

You start your timer, pour the developer in, seal the lid tightly, tap it to your table forcefully (to let the bubbles go) and then proceed to invert the tank for the first 30 seconds. Then invert 3 or 4 times on each minute.

If you like the Massive Dev Chart you will love the [Massive Dev Chart Timer](https://www.digitaltruth.com/apps/mdc/) app. It has all the times + audible timer. I found that very helpful.

As always: if in doubt consult the film datasheet - https://www.ilfordphoto.com/amfile/file/download/file/1903/product/694/ - it will give you a good baseline for your process to build upon.

Comment: Thanks I just get the app you suggested. Great stuff. By the way at the app, when time is running and the rotating tank is NOT on, what do you do in that period?

Comment: You let the tank rest for a minute or so, and you pick up a nice book. That's why I like the audible signal to wake me up (first a warning, and then tic-toc-turn). The app gives the signal for inversion even during stop bath, fixing and washing; you can disregard these.

Comment: thanks 1) At the end of inversion how long we should hit the tank to let go the bubble. Does the app indicate that? 2) If we want to do push development how can we see that in the App?

Comment: The tap is up to you; it's duration is negligible. As for pushing: in the app you pick the relevant ISO (say HP5 @ 800 is 1 stop push).